# QMF - Running Bank Column

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm trying to create a column in my QMF SQL that will tally a running bank of usage (not a running total).  If I have a list of months, my net usage, I would like a third column to record any 'leftover' usage that I can use for a later period.

Data (Run_Bank is my desired column):

```
Month   Net_Usg    Run_Bank
12/17   82         433
11/17   49         515
10/17   0          564
09/17   -11        564
08/17   -42        553
07/17   -87        511
06/17   -50        424
05/17   -101       374
04/17   -113       273
03/17   -70        160
02/17   -90        90
01/17   27         0
```

Starting on 1/17, I had a net of 27, and did not bank any excess usage.  In the following month (2/17) I had an overall net of -90 which enabled me to bank 90 to use later.  I continued banking excess usage month after month until 11/17, at which time my net was 49 so I had to dip into the bank to cover it.

I have SQL that tallies a running total, and I don't know if it's even possible to accomplish what I'm requesting help with.  Here is my SQL to tally the running total, if this helps:

```
with data as
(SELECT Month, net_usg
FROM Table A)
select d.Month, d.net_usg,(select sum(e.net_usg)
FROM data e
where e.month = d.month
and e.month <= d.month) Running_Total 
FROM data d
```